# Collapse two collections to one in laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I need help with collapse my collections.
Its my code

```
public function showFriends(){
            $request1 = DB::table('friends_users')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends_users.user_id')
                ->where([['friend_id', '=',Auth::user()->id],['accepted', '=',true]])
                ->orWhere([['user_id','=',Auth::user()->id],['accepted','= ',true]])
                ->get();

                $request2 = DB::table('friends_users')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends_users.friend_id')
                    ->where([['user_id','=',Auth::user()->id] , ['accepted','=',true]])
                    ->get();

                    $all = collect($request1,$request2)->collapse();
        return $all;

    }
```

Problem is in $all variable because it return empty collection. Thank you for help.

Comment: Try this `$collection = collect($request1,$request2);`
`$collapsed = $collection->collapse();`

Comment: It returns same empty collection :/

Comment: Can you try $req1->merge($req2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the merge method on collections:

```
 $all = $request1->merge($request2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$collection = collect($request1,$request2);
$collapsed = $collection->collapse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this potentially with one query by utilizing [`union`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions):

```
public function showFriends(){
    $query1 = DB::table('friends_users')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends_users.user_id')
        ->where([['friend_id', '=',Auth::user()->id],['accepted', '=',true]])
        ->orWhere([['user_id','=',Auth::user()->id],['accepted','= ',true]]);

    $request = DB::table('friends_users')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends_users.friend_id')
        ->where([['user_id','=',Auth::user()->id] , ['accepted','=',true]])
        ->union($query1)
        ->get();


    return $request;
    return $request->all(); // If you want an array rather than collection
}
```

The Laravel [Documentation on unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions):

> The query builder also provides a quick way to "union" two queries
>   together. For example, you may create an initial query and use the
>   union method to union it with a second query